# How can I set IIS error page with Angular App

Tags: angular, iis

I actually work on an Angular web application.
I set in angular a error page :

```
{ path : "not-found", component : NotFoundComponent},
{ path: '**', component : NotFoundComponent }
```

I do a template also.

I try to configure the custom error pages in IIS.

I go on IIS, I click on `error pages` -> `Edit Feature Settings` and I choose `Custom error pages`.
In `default page` section, my page type is File and Path is 
`dist/out-tsc/src/app/dont-found/dont-found.component`

After that i click on row `404 status code` in `response action` I choose `insert content from static file into the rror response` I choose the same file then the default page path.

The problem is when I wrote a wrong URL page it show me my code, it doesn't show me my template.

Here it's my not-found.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.css']
})
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document : any) { 
  }
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#910000d1"
  }

}
```

Here it's my not-found.component.html

```
<p>404 not found</p>
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: Hey @Soleyne, can you share your code on stackblitz?

Comment: Hi @BananaSenpai the code of my notFoundComponent ?

Comment: Can you show me the line where you are using/importing the file who's code shows up on the page.

Comment: @BananaSenpai I edit :)